# Allocating Memory for string in c?

Tags: c, memory, sizeof, allocation

How do i allocate the memory for a given char array *bla in c?

```
blaarray = (char*)malloc(strlen(bla)*sizeof(bla));
```

or

```
blaarray = (char*)malloc(strlen(bla)*sizeof(char*));
```

or neither?

thanks

**note edits to reflect silly typo. I accidently pasted the options incorrectly

Comment: Your last guess: neither. In both cases, the brackets don't match in pairs, so it's not clear what you are trying to do. But my guess is to allocate memory enough to store one `size_t` type variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want `blaarray` to be of the same size as the string `bla`

```
blaarray = malloc((strlen(bla)+1) * sizeof(char));
```

Now let me explain some points.

1) To get the length of a string, use only `strlen()` not `sizeof`

2) `1` has to be added because `strlen()` does not include the `\0` character while returning the length

3) `char*` is a pointer to `char`, to get size of a `char`, one should do `sizeof(char)`

4) Off course you need to declare `blaarray`, which you can do like

```
char* blaarray;
```

5) You do not need to cast the return of `malloc()`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

6) `sizeof(char)` is 1, so you can skip that.

So, all in all your code should look like.

```
char* blaarray;
blaarray = malloc((strlen(bla)+1));
```

Comment: this makes sense. thanks. just one question though. if i end up not following 5, is 4 still needed?